# Part of the texture look distorted

Tags: mesh, texturing, texture-painting

I modelled a table in Blender and painted the texture in 3D coat, when I've done painting and imported the texture back in Blender, a part of the texture look distorted. I tried drawing a straight line onto the texture in Blender's texture paint mode, it still appear zigzagged on the mesh. Any idea why?

[image: 3D coat comparing to Blender]

[image: drew red lines on 2D texture]

Comment: Check your geometry if it has some unwanted internal faces. If this doesn't resolve, please upload your file.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your comment. It turns out to be bad UV unwrap that stretched the texture, the problem resolved by adding seams on all vertical edges around the table. I ruled out this possibility because 3D coat has been taking the UV unwrap perfectly, not sure why Blender doesn't.